# why I cannot apt upgrade my nvidia driver?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, upgrade

All upgradable package now is kept back even with `apt full-upgrade`. But I cannot find any conflict. aptitude cannot resolve the conflict either but it does not give out reason.

```
apt list --upgradable 
Listing... Done
libnvidia-cfg1-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-compute-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-compute-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-decode-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-decode-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-encode-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-encode-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-extra-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-fbc1-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-fbc1-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-gl-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libnvidia-gl-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.0.0-1010.10+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.0.0-1010.10]
linux-modules-nvidia-525-oem-22.04b/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.0.0-1010.10+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.0.0-1010.10]
linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.0.0-1010.10+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.0.0-1010.10]
linux-signatures-nvidia-6.0.0-1010-oem/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.0.0-1010.10+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.0.0-1010.10]
nvidia-compute-utils-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
nvidia-driver-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
nvidia-kernel-common-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
nvidia-kernel-source-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
nvidia-utils-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
update-notifier-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 3.192.54.3 all [upgradable from: 3.192.54]
update-notifier/jammy-updates 3.192.54.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.192.54]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525/jammy-updates,jammy-security 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
```

After run with debug flags, it seems the nvidia-dkms-525 is not installed. But why cannot the apt just install the dependencies? I added `--with-new-pkgs`, but it still kept back.

```
apt -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes --with-new-pkgs upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Entering ResolveByKeep 10%
  Dependencies are not satisfied for nvidia-driver-525:amd64 < 525.60.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 | 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii pumH Ib >
Package nvidia-driver-525:amd64 nvidia-driver-525:amd64 Depends on nvidia-dkms-525:amd64 < none | 525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @un umH > (<= 525.60.11-1)
  Keeping Package linux-modules-nvidia-525-oem-22.04b:amd64 due to Depends
  Dependencies are not satisfied for linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 < 6.0.0-1010.10 -> 6.0.0-1010.10+1 @ii umU Ib >
Keeping package linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64
  Dependencies are not satisfied for linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 < 6.0.0-1010.10 | 6.0.0-1010.10+1 @ii umH Ib >
Package linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 Depends on linux-signatures-nvidia-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 < 6.0.0-1010.10 -> 6.0.0-1010.10+1 @ii umU > (= 6.0.0-1010.10)
  Keeping Package linux-signatures-nvidia-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 due to Depends
  Dependencies are not satisfied for linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 < 6.0.0-1010.10 | 6.0.0-1010.10+1 @ii umH Ib >
  Dependencies are not satisfied for linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 < 6.0.0-1010.10 | 6.0.0-1010.10+1 @ii umH Ib >
  Dependencies are not satisfied for linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 < 6.0.0-1010.10 | 6.0.0-1010.10+1 @ii umH Ib >
Package linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 Depends on linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 < 6.0.0-1010.10 -> 6.0.0-1010.10+1 @ii umU > (= 6.0.0-1010.10)
  Keeping Package linux-objects-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1010-oem:amd64 due to Depends
Calculating upgrade... Done
```

Interesting `sudo apt reinstall nvidia-driver-525` works. it removed an old kernel `linux-modules-nvidia-525-6.0.0-1009-oem`. But that is automatically installed anyway. the full-upgrade show be able to remove it when there is conflict. Can anyone tell me how to avoid this kind of trouble in the first place?

Now there are 2 packages still cannot be upgrade:

```
apt -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  update-notifier update-notifier-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

But why? there is no conflict at all.

Comment: Please show us the complete output of `apt cache policy update-notifier-common`

Comment: too late. I manually installed update-notifier then it works. I did not see any problem in the policy though.